# Search for a range of numbers in a .txt (find the number 100 in "randomthing = 100"

Tags: python, list, search

I am writing a program to calculate the bpm of your steps and recommend songs with similar bpms.
I am having trouble figuring out how to search the list of songs after getting the bpm.
this is the program right now:

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Timer
scnds = 10
turn = 0
bpm = 0
num = 0

window = Tk()
window.title("BPMplayer")
window.geometry("470x260")

def bpmMain():
    global num
    bpm = num*scnds
    bpm = str(bpm)
    your_bpm = Entry(window)
    your_bpm.insert(END, "Your bpm: " + bpm)
    print(bpm)
    your_bpm.pack()

bpmtrack = Timer(scnds, bpmMain)

def addBeat():
    global num
    num += 1

def runBpm():
    global turn
    if turn == 1:
        addBeat()

    if turn == 0:
        bpmtrack.start()
        turn =+ 1
        ClicktoStart['text'] = "Click"

ClicktoStart = Button(window, text="Click to Start", padx=200, pady=100, command=runBpm)
ClicktoStart.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Library needed: regular expression

```
import re
```

Preparing data:

```
text = "randomthing = 100, rand2 = 99, rand3 = 67, rand4 = 8"
```

Define regular expression: one space and one or more digits.

```
p = re.compile(r'\s(\d+)')
```

Array of matches: a

```
a = p.findall(text)
print(a)
```

Output:
['100', '99', '67', '8']

Comment: how would i search for only numbers between say 90 and 110. also how would i make it so it doesnt just print the item it prints the whole "randomthing = 100"

Comment: Instead of p = re.compile(...), put p = re.compile("randomthing = (?:1[0-1]\d|9\d)"gm). It works from 90 until 119.